# When I turn off the ik, the leg bone turns

Tags: rigging

I made legs and arms out of an ik.
And I could switch between fk and ik.
But if I switch from ik to fk, the bone turns and faces turn.
If I switch from ik to fk, can I prevent the bone from rotating?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all bones involved in the IK chain (looks like there's two of them).  In pose, ctrl a (apply) -> visual transform to pose.  Now, turn off IK.

Comment: thank you solve it

Comment: But my arm isn't working properly. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fitting the bone roll to the side axis, so it works.[image]